# Google Webfonts with TideSDK

Tags: font-face, embedded-fonts, google-webfonts, tidesdk

Have just discovered TideSDK and look forward to the upcoming 1.4.0 build.  I am utilizing the TideSDK Developer on Windows 7 32-bit and have the HelloWorld app up and running... now I am having fun trying lots of CSS3/HTML5 code snippets to see what works with the current beta release.  Trying to use Google webfonts does not seem to work... is this correct?  I saw (old) discussions about font usage on windows with appcelerator Titanium, but don't know the current status.  Is this expected to be included in the upcoming release?  I am very enthused about this project (at it's current level of completion, it is already amazing !!!)  I plan to develop a desktop application for Windows/Mac after I get a better understanding of TideSDK.   I will be using jQuery and designing the app's UI with webpage-like techniques, and not having to fight multiple HTML5/CSS3 implementations will be great!  Thanks for any suggestions about (Google) font usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although upcoming release may solve font usage issues (to include Google fonts), I found that
@font-face with SVG fonts works with current (1.3.1) TideSDK release.
For example, download TangerineBold "Font Kit" from Font Squirrel -- only need the SVG font.
Then include the following in your style sheet:

```
@font-face { 
   font-family: 'TangerineBold'; 
     src: url('Tangerine_Bold-webfont.svg#TangerineBold') format('svg'); 
     font-weight: normal; 
     font-style: normal; 
}
```

and style elements with:

```
font-family: 'TangerineBold';
```

**Further explanation** (*added 3/19/2013*):  I have given more details of custome font usage in TideSDK 1.3.1-beta on my blog, [here](http://www.neologotech.com/2013/03/19/custom-fonts-in-windows-desktop-apps-created-with-tidesdk-1-3-1-beta/)

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK current release does contain older webkit. Because of this the latest html5/css3 support may be a bit less. With newer webkit coming in upcoming release its gonna get solved so we should be getting the latest webkit builds on each of the platforms providing maximum standard support.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response...  I'll be watching for the 1.4.0 release!

Comment: Update:  SVG font files can be used with current 1.3.1 release of TideSDK.  Free SVG fonts are available from Font Squirrel, and elsewhere. For example: @font-face {
    font-family: 'TangerineBold';
    src: url('Tangerine_Bold-webfont.svg#TangerineBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}